# With wireshark how can I filter by packet size?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I can filter for packet lengths using a display filter containing data.len >= XXX, but I'd really like to use a capture filter for this for efficiency... is there a way to do it?

Comment: Kyle's answer is correct. If you ever do need to use the display filter again, frame.len would be a better choice. "frame" is guaranteed to match every packet. The "data" dissector is usually only called as a last resort, and may not match very many packets.

Comment: cool, thanks for the info. I'll use frame.len from now on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said in your comment:

```
greater <length>
less <length>
```

They also happen to be in this [handy tcpdump cheat sheet](http://www.packetlife.net/blog/2008/oct/18/cheat-sheets-tcpdump-and-wireshark/) I have on my wall.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark uses the same capture filter syntax as tcpdump, and it [doesn't look like that's an option](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~marios/ethereal-tcpdump.pdf)

Comment: +1 for the link to the documentation... but you missed the "greater" option. Apparently, there is also a "len" option.

Comment: Wow, yup. You're entirely correct- I was reading it looking for "size" and totally missed "len." Lame :-)